# Mule (Dataweave) transform JSON array to object

Tags: dataweave

How to write dataweave for given input and output
Input:

```
[
 "abcd",
 "efgh"
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "abcd":{
    "firstname": "xyz",
    "lastname" : "pqr"
  },
  "efgh" :{
    "firstname": "klm",
    "lastname" : "nop"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where first and last name come from in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reduce()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-reduce) function to transform an array into an object. Each element of the array into is transformed into an object (key-value pairs) and then is concatenated in the accumulator so  all key-pairs are joined into a single object. For the key of each key-pair we use the array element.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce ((item, accumulator={}) 
           -> accumulator ++ {(item): { firstname: "abc", lastname: "def"}} 
)
```

Ouptut:

```json
{
  "abcd": {
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "def"
  },
  "efgh": {
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "def"
  }
}
```

You didn't specify how firstname and lastname are transformed. I used literal strings for the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{(payload map {
    (($) : ({ firstname: "abc", lastname: "def"}))

})}
```

Output:

```
{
  "abcd": {
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "def"
  },
  "efgh": {
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "def"
  }
}
```